# Turn register_globals on for just one app

Tags: php, register-globals

We've got a client application that relies on register_globals turned on to work, but we're hosting it on a our shared server, and don't want to turn register_globals on in our main php.ini file.

I tried inserting `ini_set ( 'register_globals' , 'On' );` but it didn't work. Why didn't it? And is there a better way?

Comment: rewrite the app, no really, it is the less painful option.

Comment: ok, my rate is $150 an hour, lets get started.

Comment: you'll need a bucket for your tears

Comment: I would rent an additional virtual server for that application to avoid problems; who knows what other security problems it has...

Comment: And if it's really that bad, @Dagon will need a bucket for the money as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could always try to put:

```
 extract($_REQUEST,EXTR_SKIP); //thanks @Wayne Whitty
```

on top of every files. It would yeld the same results as far as I know.
But really, REALLY, its bad bad bad to use these. I'd look for a way to change the code. But sometimes you have no choice.

Comment: Just thought I'd add that OP should probably use EXTR_SKIP as a second parameter. By default, extract is set to EXTR_OVERWRITE.

    extract($_REQUEST,EXTR_SKIP);

Answer (score 5):

From the php documentation:

> Please note that register_globals cannot be set at runtime
>   (ini_set()). Although, you can use .htaccess if your host allows it as
>   described above. An example .htaccess entry: php_flag register_globals
>   off.

[link to php documentation on register_globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals)

Answer (score 1):

**register_globals** could be set only in php.ini. Not runtime by **ini_set**
You can only read this setting by follow code:

```
ini_get('register_globals');
```